# Linux : how to get avg time and turnaround time using Completely Fair Scheduler

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am working in a Completely fair scheduler which is the default scheduler in Linux (fair. c). I am trying to find out the avg waiting time and avg turnaround time using the default scheduler.
Initially, I planned to write a separate prog that uses the default scheduler and gives the avg times. But now I am not sure how to implement it. Is there any way to get the avg time using the CFS scheduler?

Comment: You'll likely need some form of kernel tracing. For example, [System Tap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/)